# Summation of $2^n$ where $n$ is even or odd

Tags: summation

I need the summation formula for the following:

$2^0+2^1+2^3+2^5+\cdots+2^n$, $n$ is even i.e.

$2^0+2^2+2^4+2^6+\cdots+2^n$, $n$ is odd

I am aware that the formula of

$2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^n = 2^{n+1}-1$. But can anyone help me with a approach so solve such kind of problems.

Comment: Are you sure that the first sum is to start with $2^0$ and not $2^1$?  And didn't you mix up "even" and "odd"?

Comment: @Frunobulax Note that you can always compute the sum starting with $2^1$ and then add $2^0$ to the final result.

Comment: @Surb: I know that.  My question was if the OP knew what he was asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] Thanks for accepting. This is an even more straightforward approach:

$$\begin{align}
S&=2^0+2^2+2^4+ \cdots +2^{2m}\\
&=4^0+4^1+4^2+\cdots +4^m\\
&=\frac 13 (4^{m+1}-1)\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
S'&=2^1+2^3+2^5+ \cdots +2^{2m+1}\\
&=2(4^0+4^1+4^2+\cdots +4^m)\\
&=\frac 23 (4^{m+1}-1)\end{align}$$

---

[ORIGINAL ANSWER] Consider the case where $n$ is even, i.e. $n=2m$.

Let 
$$\begin{align}
S&=2^0+2^2+2^4+\cdots +2^{2m}\\
2S&=2^1+2^3+2^5+\cdots+2^{2m+1}\end{align}$$

Adding:
$$\begin{align}3S&=2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+\cdots+2^{2m+1}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{2m+1}2^r\\
&=2^{2m+2}-1\\
S&=\frac 13 \left(2^{2m+2}-1\right)\\
&=\frac 13 \left(4^{m+1}-1\right)\end{align}$$

---

Similarly, for the case where $n$ is odd, i.e. $n=2m+1$,

$$\begin{align}S'&=2^1+2^3+2^5+\cdots+2^{2m+1}\\
&=2(2^0+2^2+2^4+\cdots +2^{2m})\\
&=2S\\
&=\frac 23 \left(4^{m+1}-1\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: But this summation cannot be a fraction right ? So, will it (the part except 1/3) be always divisible by 3 ?

Comment: Yes, because $(4^{m+1}-1)=(4-1)(4^m+4^{m-1}+\cdots +1)=3(4^m+4^{m-1}+\cdots +1)$ is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$\sum_{k=0}^m2^{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^m\left(2^2\right)^{k}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=0}^m2^{2k-1} = 2^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^m\left(2^2\right)^{k}$$

Comment: Very neat answer.

Comment: @hypergeometric Thanks :)

Comment: Well the index in the second is $k=1$

Comment: @kingW3 Well my goal was to highlight the formula $\sum_{k=0}^m x^k = \frac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x},x \neq 1$ (which seems to be know by the OP) in both cases. I think it is now the job of the OP to add/remove "extremal terms" in order to recover the sums he wants to compute.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for an approach to this kind of problem. The approach is: stop looking for a formula and think about techniques. The technique for dealing with $1+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^n$ is this. Suppose it is $S$. Now consider $xS$. That is the same except that it has lost a term at the front and gained one at the back. So it is now easy to write down a formula for $S$.

How do you apply that to $x+x^3+x^5+\dots+x^{2n+1}$? What could you multiply the sum by to give something almost the same. Answer, multiply by $x^2$.

Of course, it is useful to know some formulae by heart. That saves time and it also gives you something to work from. But it is no good just saying I don't know a formula that exactly fits the new problem, so I will give up. The question is whether the new problem is similar to something I already know. If it is how could I adapt that ...